# what it means "One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "input_4"?

Tags: c, mex

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "string.h"

void mexFunction( int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  double out, out_1, out_2;
  out_1 = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
  out_2 = mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
  out= out_1+out_2;
  mexPrintf("%f\n ", out);
  return;
 }
```

i wrote this function to sum the two numbers. it worked.

> > mex input_4.c
> >     input_4(1,2)
> >     3.000000

but it says error when this output value was assigned to a variable in the command window..for example

> > b=input_4(1,2);
> >     3.000000 One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "input_4".
> >     why it is not assigning the value of 3 to b.
> >     can anyone help me what it means?
> >     thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are currently not assigning any output that MATLAB will recognize. You need to assign outputs to `plhs`. Here's how I would do it:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  double out, out_1, out_2;
  out_1 = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
  out_2 = mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
  out= out_1+out_2;
  if (nlhs == 1)
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(out);
  else if (nlhs > 1)
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mexFile:tooManyOutputs", "Too many outputs!");
  else
    mexPrintf("%f\n ", out);

  return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because your function return type is `void`. It is not returning anything. What you see as output is printed by `printf`, your function didn't return it.

Try returning the value you calculated.